# A list of UK businesses whose owner supported Brexit

Tags: united-kingdom, brexit

First, sorry if this isn't a question that can be asked in here, if there is a more suitable stack-exchange please let me know and I will delete, no need to down vote.

I am looking for a list of famous UK businesses and their leaders/owners who supported Brexit, I only know of Warburtons and Wetherspoons (AFAIK).

No specific criteria other than the above.

I would like to see how are/will they doing/do after Brexit been achieved.

Comment: Support/funding of a political goal is surely on topic, if a bit historical rather than timely in 2021... https://www.theguardian.com/business/2018/sep/01/uk-business-figures-still-backing-brexit

Comment: It would be way more interesting to read their reasoning behind their stance, rather than a simple list.

Comment: This question [is being discussed on meta](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6010/when-are-list-questions-too-broad).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jim Ratcliff reportedly did/does. And [he is/was](https://www.theguardian.com/business/2018/sep/01/uk-business-figures-still-backing-brexit) "ranked by the Sunday Times as Britain’s richest person, with a fortune estimated at £21bn" at least in 2018. Another [article](https://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/2018/may/13/fracking-mogul-jim-ratcliffe-uk-richest-person-ineos-sunday-times-rich-list) dubbed him a "fracking mogul" presumably because of his share in the UK pretrochemical industry. Supposedly he [moved](https://www.theguardian.com/business/2020/sep/25/sir-jim-ratcliffe-uks-richest-person-moves-to-tax-free-monaco-brexit-ineos-domicile) to Monaco "for tax purposes" though, in 2020.

[Reportedly](https://edition.cnn.com/2020/12/09/business/jim-ratcliffe-grenadier-brexit/index.html) James Dyson, 4th richest in the UK (2021), also supported Brexit. At least he seems to have made more mediatized [statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Dyson#Pro-Brexit).

Answer (score 0):

The Guardian ran an article in 2018 on the business owners [still backing Brexit](https://www.theguardian.com/business/2018/sep/01/uk-business-figures-still-backing-brexit) at that stage.

These included

- James Dyson (Dyson)
- Jim Ratcliffe (Ineos)
- Helena Morrissey (Legal and General)
- Anthony Bamford (JCB)
- Tim Martin (Weatherspoons)
- Simon Wolfson (Next)

This is fairly obviously not a complete list.

Comment: This should have been added to the existing answer instead of posting a new one. Having multiple answers with part of the list doesn't do anyone any good.